# Could you use ultrasonic vibrations instead of a roller with an SLS/SLM printer?

Tags: sls, slm

I've been thinking, SLS/SLM printers currently use a roller to spread 3d printing substrate, but wouldn't ultrasonic vibrations spread the substrate more cleanly, accurately, and with greater density than a roller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

The problem is twofold. Resonance and Granular convection

### Resonance

Let's start with an empty box. We toss in some powder to create the first layer and use an ultrasonic to create a first layer. What happens? The bed starts to resonate depending on the sound you send into it in patterns - and the powder starts to form valleys and ridges along them as one can see in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvJAgrUBF4w).

### Granular Convection

What happens if one shakes a box of fine granulate that contains larger items? [Granular convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granular_convection) happens! All items raise simultaneously and the small items start to fall first, resulting in them getting under the larger ones, so as a result end up pushing the large items up.

Because of both effects, there won't be an even layer **and** it would raise the items printed, even if we managed to get good layers.